# Where is the routing in the example of ASP.Net Core 6 WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've just started looking at webApi core 6, and the weatherforecast example. I'm using Postman and have commented out Swagger and SwaggerUI in Program.cs,  the URL https://localhost:7192/WeatherForecast works, so I'm assuming 'WeatherForecast' is the controller name and it defaults to the httpGet method of Get()? But I'm trying to find the routing, because that HttpGet has an attribute name of "GetWeatherForecast" which doesn't work in postman.

Now, I've added a second Get method just to see how this will be hit, like below, but it says error 'AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: ... ' when I used the URL above, but using 'GetBlah' nor 'GetTest' doesn't work as well, so how is the routing mapped?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetTest")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetBlah()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Route] attribute in the controller helps you to access `/WeatherForecast`. And based on the HTTP Request method controller action methods are invoked. Since you're trying to access the `/Weatherforecast` endpoint - it is will invoke the GET method. When you're putting an attribute like `[HttpGet(Name = "GetTest")]` you're specifying the name of the action method - it has nothing to do with routing. If you like to expose this method, you need to add it like this. `[HttpGet("GetTest",Name = "GetTest")]` - the first parameter is the template and second one is the name - it is for Open API.

Comment: I thought you can do it like /[controller]/[action]/ ? So what i was doing was /WeatherForecast/GetBlah since that is the action method, but still doesn't work. Where is the routing of webapi defined? The launchsettings.json only contains LaunchUrl with swagger as the value...

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. But in WebApi attribute routing is preferred. Because of that, there is a route attribute in the controller. To achieve the same, you just need to modify the HTTP GET attribute like this - `[HttpGet("[action]", Name = "GetTest")]`. Configuring conventional routing in web api is little complex.

Comment: To enable convention-based routing in Web API - you need to modify `MapControllers` to `MapDefaultControllerRoute` and remove the `ApiController` attribute from the controller and other routing info. Then you will be able to access the action methods like `[controller]/[action]`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.In program, I donot change app.MapControllers(); I just remove [ApiController], and add route.

```
   [Route("api/WeatherForecast")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Route("~/api/Get")]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]

        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
        [Route("~/api/GetBlah")]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetTest")]

        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetBlah()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

    }
```

result:

[image]